# Eigenspace and polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My prof introduced us to eigenvectors and eigenvalues today. He then gave us the following theorem:

> Theorem 6.6: Let $A$ be a square matrix, let $\gamma$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $m$. Then the dimension of the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\gamma$ is less than or equal to $m$.

He omitted the proof because he said it was beyond the scope of the course. I'm really curious about the proof though: could someone provide me with a proof that doesn't require any knowledge beyond the basics of subspaces and eigenvectors?

Thanks!

Comment: What course is that where that basic theorem is "beyond" its scope?

Comment: @DonAntonio Grade 8 math. We had a prof come give us a guest lecture.

Comment: Well, then the whole thing is really out of scope...

Comment: @DonAntonio Not really. I understood all of it except for the theorem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is not conceptually difficult, it's just tedious to write down.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Let $g$ be the geometric multiplicity corresponding to some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and let $m$ be the algebraic multiplicity. We will show that $g \le m$.

Take your $g$ linearly independent eigenvectors, say $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{v}_g\}$. Extend this set to a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{v}_g,\ \mathbf{u}_{g+1},\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{u}_n\}$ for $\mathbb{F}^n$. Form the matrix $P$ with the columns of $\mathcal{B}$. Note that $P$ is invertible.

Now consider the product $P^{-1}AP$ similar to what we would do when we diagonalize the matrix. The idea is that the first $g$ columns of $P$ are eigenvectors and so will partially diagonalize the matrix. The tedious part is in working out the details (it's actually not too bad if you are familiar with block matrix multiplication), but I will skip ahead to the punchline
$$P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix}\lambda I_g & M \\ O & N\end{pmatrix}$$
where $I_g$ is the $g\times g$ identity matrix, $O$ is the $n-g\times g$ zero matrix and where $M$ and $N$ are other appropriately sized matrices (they are unimportant in the proof).

If we take the characteristic polynomial of this matrix, then $(x-\lambda)^g$ appears as a factor due to the presence of the $\lambda I_g$ submatrix. But since the characteristic polynomial is unchanged through similarity, it follows that $(x-\lambda)^g$ also appears as a factor of $A$'s characteristic polynomial. This allows us to conclude that $g \le m$.

Comment: You are using $D=P^{-1}AP$, but how do you know that A is diagnoalizable?

Comment: @Hobbit6094 I am not assuming that $A$ is diagonalizable. You can think of this as restricting the diagoanlization procedure solely to one of the eigenspaces, i.e. the matrix $P$ is not the full matrix of eigenvectors but rather the matrix with only the first few columns as eigenvectors (belonging to a single eigenspace). The resulting matrix $P^{-1}AP$ is therefore not fully diagonalized, but partially, with the number of diagonal entries depending on the number of eigenvectors you've included in $P$, i.e. the geometric multiplicity.